# Left outer Join with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone help me translate this query to LINQ? I cant find a good way to translate it, Thanks!

```
SELECT
  C.id,
  C.id_old,
  C.cus_id,
  C.namefirst,
  C.title,

  CP.id as 'cus_phone_jct.id',
  CP.contact_id,
  CP.phone_id,
  CP.ext,

  P.id as 'cus_phone.id',
  P.phone,
  P.typ_id,
  P.status_id,
  P.donotcontact

FROM cus_contact C
LEFT OUTER JOIN cus_phone_jct CP ON C.id = CP.contact_id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN cus_phone P ON CP.phone_id = P.id
WHERE C.cus_id = 4
```

Comment: Urm, could you simplify that a bit - like one field from each table?

Comment: And please throw in a little formatting. Right now i feel like taking forks to my eyes.  j/k

Comment: sorry for the crappy "cut and paste" version :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try,

```
from c in DataContext.cus_contact
join cp in DataContext.cus_phone_jct on c.id equals cp.contact_id into cp2 
  from cp3 in cp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
join p in DataContext.cus_phone on cp3.phone_id equals p.id into p2 
  from p3 in p2.DefaultIfEmpty()
where c.cus_id = 4
select 
  c.id,
  cp3.id
  ...
```

Comment: That,s perfect! I need to learn more of this stuff. It looks so foreign to me right now, Thanks!